# Can we run a python script in make which generates a few .c and .h files and then build an image?

Tags: c, linux, makefile, cmake

I have a json file from which I need to generate .c and .h files and then build my image.

Is there some way through which I can run a python script first and then build c files when developer runs Make?

Comment: yes, you can do it

Comment: @bernal: what is the best way to achieve this

Comment: After searching for *cmake autogenerate source files*, [this was the first link](https://cmake.org/pipermail/cmake/2011-May/044136.html) in my results. Read it, and try searching yourself.

Answer (score 0):

In CMAKE, you can use `add_custom_command` this way, consult cmake documentation

```
add_custom_command(OUTPUT ${YOUR_OUTPUT_FILE} COMMAND your_generate_command --outputfile=${YOUR_OUTPUT_FILE} --inputfile=${YOUR_JSON_FILE} DEPENDS ${YOUR_JSON_FILE} VERBATIM)
```